Flutter/dart: How to identify drivers for large aab file sizes
I have updated some dependencies of my flutter app, and suddenly the aab file size of my release has doubled from 190mb to 380mb. Now, I get a warning when uploading to the play store.
How can I find out which dependency/package contributes how much to the app size so that I can take measures to mitigate?
Many thanks!
